# Position items left and center in Android Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android Toolbar with 2 items, a button and TextView. I want to place the button on the left and the TextView in the center. What's the best way to do this? Currently I am just adding margins to a LinearLayout but there's no guarantee that the TextView is totally centered.

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: You need to use relative layout instead of linear layout and then use android:layout_alignParentStart="true" for left button and use android:layout_centerInParent="true" for textview to make it center aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Text Here"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```